# How to add a comma to the end of each line

Tags: python, mysql, file-io

I am trying to write a line (which is a list of a few values) to a text file.  I need commas at the end of every line.  This is for an assignment where I am pushing the information in each line into a database. The line does need to be exactly as I have written it above, i.e. the number at the front and the number at the end cannot be strings.

And this is the line I'm using to actually write to the file. The format i need is:

6,"word here","another word here",0,\n

edit: here's the code I'm using so far. openedFile is a csv file.

```
try:
    reader = csv.reader(openedFile)
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile,delimiter=',')
    lines = []
    for row in reader:
        temp = []
        category = row[14]
        slug = slugger(category).lower()
        lines.append([termIDCount,category,slug,0])
        termIDCount += 1

    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(line)

finally:
    openedFile.close()
```

Comment: This can be done in many different way.. Why don't you post a minimum working example so that we can understand more on what is your intent?

Answer (score 1):

For a very simple approach:

```
termIDCount = 6
category = "word here"
slug = "another word here"
lines = []
lines.append([termIDCount,category,slug,0])

for line in lines:
    s = '(' + str(line[0])
    for i in line[1:]:
        s += ',' + str(i)
    s += '),'
    print(s)
    #writer.writerow(line)
```

EDIT:

```
termIDCount = 6
category = "word here"
slug = "another word here"
lines = []
lines.append([termIDCount,category,slug,0])

for line in lines:
    s = '(' + str(line[0])
    for i in line[1:]:
        if( type(i) == str ):
            s += ',"' + str(i) + '"'
        else:
            s += ',' + str(i)
    s += '),'
    print(s)
    #writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: @redeagle47: do you want the `"` for each string?

Comment: well the problem is I'm not sure. I think the 6 and 0 have to be integers. I'm pushing these values into a msyql database, and I need the types to match.

Comment: @redeagle47: I see but this issue is different from what you asked

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be as simple as:

```
termIDCount = 6
category = "word here"
slug = "another word here"
lines = []
lines.append(','.join([str(termIDCount),category,slug,str(0)]))

with open('./foofile.csv','w') as f:
    for l in lines:
         f.write('('+l+'),\n')
```

The "stringing" of the lines could be done further below in the for loop as well if you require them to be lists.